# Cómo recuperar datos que envio desde un Dialog hacia una Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, activity, dialog

***Amigos, buen día***, acudo a ustedes para que me guien y me ayuden a resolver este problema.

Tengo un incoveniente con una Activity que a la vez es un Dialog, como primero punto, mi aplicación consta de 2 botones que lo genera un recyclerview (1era Actividad), cada botón abre una activity(Dialog), mi problema no puedo recuperar los datos, por lo veo no puedo utilizar el putExtra en el Dialog

Adjunto el código necesesario
**Código del Adaptador**

```
 ArrayList<DAO> list;
    SelectedMovies selectedMovies;
    Context context;
    Dialog dialogo;
    Button btn_add_car,btn_close_car;

  public Adapter(ArrayList<DAO> list, SelectedMovies selectedMovies, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.selectedMovies = selectedMovies;
        this.context = context;
    }

 @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderAdapterPeliculas onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_buttons,null);
        ViewHolderAdapterPeliculas vhp = new ViewHolderAdapterPeliculas(view);
        return vhp;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolderAdapterPeliculas holder, final int position) {
        holder.btn_pelis.setText(list.get(position).getName_pelicula());
        holder.btn_pelis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selected = position;
                selectedMovies.selectedMovies(list.get(position),v);
                DIALOG(v);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        if(selected==position){
            holder.btn_pelis.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00345D"));
            holder.btn_pelis.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBF00"));
        }else {
            holder.btn_pelis.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            holder.btn_pelis.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public interface SelectedMovies{
        void selectedMovies(DAO dao, View view);
    }

    public class ViewHolderAdapterPeliculas extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button btn_pelis;
        TextView txt_movie;
        ImageView img_movie;
        public ViewHolderAdapterPeliculas(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            btn_pelis = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_select);
            txt_movie = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            img_movie = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        }
    }

    private void DIALOG(View v) {
        dialogo = new Dialog(v.getContext());
        dialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.activity_modal_prod);
        dialogo.setCancelable(false);
        dialogo.show();

        btn_add_car = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_car);
        btn_add_car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(dialogo.getContext(), "Agregado al carrito", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        btn_close_car = (Button) dialogo.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_infopro);
        btn_close_car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialogo.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Este es el Main Activity donde realizo el llenado del RecyclerView

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<DAO> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewButon);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        llenar();
        adapter = new Adapter(list,this,getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void llenar(){
        list.add(new DAO("El Joker",  "Bienvenidos al Joker", R.drawable.jojer));
        list.add(new DAO("Rápidos y Furiosos",  "Bienvenidos a la novena saga de Fast Fiouruis", R.drawable.rapidos));
    }

    @Override
    public void selectedMovies(DAO dao, View view) {
        //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, modal_prod.class).putExtra("data",dao));
    }
```

Con este codigo (Archivo del Dialog.java) recupero los datos, pero con una Activity (Cosa que no quiero, si no con el Dialog)

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getExtras()!=null){
            DAO dao = (DAO) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");
            imageView.setImageResource(dao.getImage_movie());
            textView.setText(dao.getName_pelicula());
        }
```

como les dije anteriormente, me funciono pero llamando a la Actividad, pero la verdad quisiera que sea con el Dialog, espero que me puedan ayudar, les quedo muy agradecido

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un Dialog con un método de instancia como este:

```
public static MyDialog crearInstancia(SelectedMovies data) {
    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("data", data);
    dialog.setArguments(args);
    return dialog;
}
```

Después desde el Dialog (preferiblemente en el método **onCreateDialog()**) recuperas los datos:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
SelectedMovies movies = args.getSerializable("data");
```

Para mostrar el Dialog simplemente debes crear su instancia usando el método de arriba, pasando los datos:

```
SelectedMovies datos = /* origen de datos */
MyDialog instancia = MyDialog.crearInstancia(datos);
instancia.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
```